# Firebase Hosting : How to Redirect URLs Based on Origin Domain

Tags: firebase, single-page-application, google-cloud-functions, firebase-hosting

I have rules as follows, but I want this to only work if origin is any other domain except the current domain.

If my domain is friends.com, everything should go to index, otherwise be handled like below. e.g, if origin is from Google, with a path like `friends.com/user`, that should call an `firebase https function` instead of going to index.

```
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": "y",
        "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
        "rewrites": [{
                "source": "/user",
                "function": "user"
            },
            {
                "source": "/post",
                "function": "post"
            },
            {
                "source": "/*",
                "destination": "/index.html"
            }
        ],
        "headers": [{
            "source": "/css/**",
            "headers": [{
                "key": "Cache-Control",
                "value": "max-age=0"
            }]
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't currently perform rewrites or redirects based on the domain, only paths. To do this, you would need to set up a separate Firebase project to do the redirects for `friends.com` vs. other domains.